# How can i hide columns in JQuery server-side DataTables?

Tags: datatables

How can i hide columns in JQuery server-side DataTables.

bellow code not working server-side.

```
$(function() {
        $("#example").each(function() {
        $(this).find('td:eq(1)').addClass("hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg");
        $(this).find('td:eq(2)').addClass("hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg");           
        });
```

---

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`columns.visible`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) option during initialization or [`column().visible()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()) API method after initializaiton to enable or disable the display of this column.

For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable().column(1).visible(false);
```

If you need to hide columns on smaller screen devices only, look into using [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use `aoColumnDefs` to invisible whatever column you need by changing values of `aTargets`:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
        "bSearchable": false,
        "bVisible": false,
        "aTargets": [0]
        }
    ]
});​
```